# Replace div after form submit Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a form that when a user submits, the form the #search div is replaced by the #loading div that shows a loading image. So far it works fine.

The problem I have now is that I want the #loading div to be replaced by the #results 10 seconds after the #loading div is shown.

Can someone please help with the last few lines of code?

Here it is so far:

```
<div id="search">
    <div id="search-area">
        <h1>Heading Here</h1>
        <form id="target" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
            <input type="text" value="http://"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Analyze"/>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>

<script>
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
    $("#search").slideUp("slow", function() {
        $(this).replaceWith("<div id='loading'>" + 
                                "<h2>Please be patient while<br/>" +
                                "we analyse your website.</h2>" + 
                                "<img src='/images/progress.gif'/>" + 
                            "</div>");
    });
    $("#loading").delay(10000).slideUp("slow", function(){
        $(this).replaceWith("<div id='results'>" +
                                "<h2>Here are the results</h2>" +
                            "</div>");
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Comment: not a good practice to wait for a particular amount of time to show result .. wat if the result is not available after  secs?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#target").submit(function (event) {

    $("#search").slideUp("slow", function () {            
        $(this).replaceWith("<div id='loading'><img src='/images/loading.gif'/></div>");            
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#loading").slideUp("slow", function () {
            $(this).replaceWith("<div id='done'>Done!</div>");
        });
    }, 10000);

    event.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your answer. That doesn't do it, the #loading div stays visible and #results still doesn't appear. I have updated my edit above also.

Comment: I made some changes. Try that and let me know.

Comment: check edit. The second item doesn't have anything to bind to, so use setTimeout. And A J is correct, should use a load or ready func to determine if your result is returned.

Answer (score 0):

The loading div is not available until after the first animation finishes, the second animation needs to be inside the callback:

```
$("#target").submit(function (event) {
    $("#search").slideUp("slow", function () {
        $(this).replaceWith("<div id='loading'>" +
            "<h2>Please be patient while<br/>" +
            "we analyse your website.</h2>" +
            "<img src='/images/progress.gif'/>" +
            "</div>");
        $("#loading").delay(10000).slideUp("slow", function () {
            $(this).replaceWith("<div id='results'>" +
                "<h2>Here are the results</h2>" +
                "</div>");
        });
    })
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/_wilmer/TrcLy/1/)